# How is possible to show difference between pixels in same position in successive frames?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

i want to show the difference value between pixels in same position in successive frames (for example 100 frames),
is it possible to use standard deviation value for determine the number of pixels above or below of this value in successive frames for each pixel position?
or is there another method to show the value of pixels difference in same position in successive frames?

Comment: Hi Sarina! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image data is the same dimension for each frame, then you can simply concatenate all of your data along a given dimension. Below I will use the 4th dimension since your data may actually be RGB data.

```
% Assumes that your input data is a cell array of images
combined = cat(4, images{:});
```

The dimension of this data is now [nRows, nColumns, nChannels, nTime].

Then you can specify the dimension in which to apply many operations in MATLAB. For example if you want to find the differences over time you could use the [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function (Note the specification of the 4th dimension as the third argument):

```
differences = diff(combined, [], 4);
```

Similarly you could compute the [standard deviation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html) of a pixel over time (Again specifying that you want standard deviation along the 4th dimension).

```
std_over_time = std(combined, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer,